# React - Conditional Element in a map Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I want to display a different link in this map function,
If x is for example 3 i want to show`<Link>Put</Link>` otherwise i want to show `<Link>Remove</Link>`. I am trying to do some conditional but i get errors, how can i write it down?

```
const mapWorkplace = (arr: SuggestedWorkplace[], deallocation: boolean) =>
  arr.map((x, i) => ({
    ...x,
    action: <Link>Put</Link> || <Link>Remove</Link> ,
    __props: {
      style: { background: !(i % 2) ? "#fff" : "rgba(233, 249, 249, .6)" }
    }
  }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your error comes from the value of `action`, you can do it using a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
const mapWorkplace = (arr: SuggestedWorkplace[], deallocation: boolean) =>
  arr.map((x, i) => ({
    ...x,
    action: x === 3 ? <Link>Put</Link> : <Link>Remove</Link> ,
    __props: {
      style: { background: !(i % 2) ? "#fff" : "rgba(233, 249, 249, .6)" }
    },
}));
```

Comment: Since Error is not mentioned in Question, it is better to point out that we need to `import React from 'react';` too